# sed grouping cancels out results?

Tags: windows, regex, sed

When running the following `sed` command under Windows (to uppercase a keyword which isn't part of another word):

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" -e "s/[^a-z]*declare[^a-z]*/DECLARE/I" "SqlFile.sql"
```

will turn `declare @returntable` from `SqlFile.Sql` into `DECLAREreturntable`.

But adding capturing groups to transport the surrounding characters to the destination string, will leave `declare` lowercased:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" -e "s/([^a-z]*)declare([^a-z]*)/\\1DECLARE\\2/I" "SqlFile.sql"
```

Why does sed apply different rules to grouped sets in comparison to ungrouped ones?

(I know that the `\b` word boundaries are a better way to uppercase keywords, but I observed this `sed` behaviour and was wondering what the reason was)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `"(foo)"` is not a capturing group for `sed`, only `"\(foo\)"` is.

Sed would normally error out that you use `\1` and `\2` without any capturing groups defined, but it doesn't because `"\\1"` apparently doesn't expand to `\1` in your shell (command.exe?) like they do in `bash`.

So you're trying to replace a string with literal parentheses with one with literal backslashes and it does not match, keeping `declare` lowercase.